# Android Emulator starts, but it doesn't run android system

Tags: android-emulator, apk, device

I try to run my app in android emulator. From the begining, everythigs works fine. I create new device in Android Vrtual Device Manager, then i run the device. After a while i can see an emulator with mobile skin - that's all, nothing else happens. The device has black screen and in the Android Monitor I see this:

[screen from Android Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pf4i.jpg)

When i try to run my app I recive this:

[screen from selecting deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LvEr.jpg)

When I try to run app from this window, somethig is going to happen. I have to wait long long time but finally, android is started on the device but meanwhile i recive error "Session 'app':Error Instaling APK. Sometimes app will run, sometimes not, but everything works very very slow. When i run app directly (without running device from AVD Manager), app is bulided and then i see a process "Waiting fro target device to come online", emulator runs but with black screen.

I have no idea what to do now. I reinstaled Android Studio twice - always the same result. 
I have to add that a few days ago everythings works perfect - very fast and without problems. Recently I was installing Ubuntu on a new partition, I've done some changes in widows driver manager. Maybe this is a reason?
What I should do now? Thanks in advance

Comment: which android system image are you using?